What is weak convergence of random permutons?
In various papers on permutons you can find statements similar to this (see Maazoun's thesis)

For any $n$ let $\sigma_n$ be a random permutation of size $n$. TFAE:

$(\mu_{\sigma_n})_n$ converges in distribution for the weak topology to some random permuton $\mu$
The random infinite vector $(\tilde{\operatorname{occ}}(\pi, \sigma_n))_{\pi\in\mathfrak S}$ converges in distribution in the
product topology


I honestly do not know what 1. actually means. It's clear that convergence of permutons is just weak convergence. What is convergence of random permutons? There are many choices one can make, obvious ones being weak convergence almost surely or weak convergence for the topology of weak convergence.
My guess would be that they use the latter. I can't really see that in the arguments though. For example to prove (1) implies (2) they argue $\mu\mapsto (\tilde{\operatorname{occ}}(\pi, \mu))$ is continuous for weak convergence, hence $\tilde{\operatorname{occ}}(\pi, \mu_{\sigma_n}) \to \tilde{\operatorname{occ}}(\pi, \mu)$. But this looks as if they make the argument for each $\omega$, that is each realization of $\mu$. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious since I have not worked with convergence of random measures before.

I'm inclined to believe that convergence of random permutons is convergence in distribution for the topology of weak convergence.
The argument regarding the continuous map $\mu\mapsto (\tilde{\operatorname{occ}}(\pi, \mu))$ works as follows:
There is the well-known Giry functor $\mathcal P : \mathsf{Pol} \to \mathsf{Pol}$ on the category of Polish spaces and continuous maps. Given a Polish space $X$ the space $\mathcal PX$ is the space of probability measures with the topology of weak convergence and given a continuous map $f : X\to Y$ between Polish spaces the map $\mathcal P f : \mathcal P X \to \mathcal PY$ is the pushforward along $f$.
Then if a map $\Phi : \mathcal PX \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, then so is $\mathcal P \Phi : \mathcal P \mathcal P X \to \mathcal P \mathbb R$, which is almost what we want.
Note that from this we can deduce the continuity of $\Phi$ wrt convergence in distribution. More generally, given a continuous map $f : X\to Y$ the map $\mathcal P f$ is continuous. Thus, if $x, x_n : \Omega \to X$ are random variables with $x_n \to x$ in distribution we have $\mathbb P \circ x^{-1}_n \to \mathbb P \circ x^{-1}$ weakly, so
$$\mathbb P \circ x_n^{-1} \circ f^{-1} = \mathcal P f(\mathbb P \circ x^{-1}_n) \to \mathcal P f(\mathbb P \circ x^{-1}) = \mathbb P \circ x^{-1} \circ f^{-1} \text{ weakly }.$$
This equivalent to $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ in distribution.
